# Is there a Python function to convert unicode literals into a readable form?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, literals

I have successfully decompiled python 2.7 files with the .pyc extension. The problem is that the original scripts contain comment blocks in Russian, and after decompiling, they were converted to raw unicode literals,

for example

```py
msg = u '\ u0444 \ u0430 \ u0439 \ u043b \ u0435'
```

and I find it difficult to transform them into a readable form. I suppose there is a function in python that accepts unicode literals as an argument and gives a readable string at the output, but my searches were in vain.

Comment: That code isn't syntactically legal; you can't have a space between the `u` prefix and the open quote. Which makes me suspicious of all the other spaces between backslashes and `u`s within the string. What is your actual code?

Comment: Here is a portion of the decompiled code.:
[link] (https://www.codepile.net/pile/2Y7XAvKj)

Comment: To work with the code, I need to convert the unicode literals into a readable form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there really spaces between the `\` and the `u` in your data? That will cause problems with parsing, so you need to remove those first. You can't use `replace(" ","")` because the string will already be formatted as `\\` if they don't precede the `u`.

Once you have the proper string, you can either (1) use python 3 or (2) import unicode support to 2.7 or (3) use `u""` strings in 2.7...

In Python 3:

```
mytext='\u0444 \u0430 \u0439 \u043b \u0435'
print(mytext)
```

Python 2.7:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
mytext='\u0444 \u0430 \u0439 \u043b \u0435'
print mytext
```

Python 2.7 w/o import:

```
mytext=u'\u0444 \u0430 \u0439 \u043b \u0435'
# note the `u` before the string. 
# In your example, you'd remove all those extra spaces
print mytext
```

Output:

```
ф а й л е
```

---

UPDATE: If your output is exactly as you have written it above, then you may be able to modify the string first to get rid of extraneous spaces, and then evaluate it to generate the proper format. (Thanks to @lenz for the comment about `literal_eval`.)

```
import ast
original = "msg = u '\ u0444 \ u0430 \ u0439 \ u043b \ u0435'"
despaced = original.replace("u '","u'").replace("\\ ","\\")
# chop off original assignment with split() and assign to new variable
cleaned  = ast.literal_eval(despaced.split("=")[1].strip())
print cleaned
```

Output:

```
ф а й л е
```

Comment: I think the string literals `u'\0444...'` aren't part of the source code, but rather input values (think `'u"\\u0444..."'`). So an additional parsing step is required, eg. using `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: Thanks. Good point. I thought about `eval` but everyone freaks out when you use it ;^) and I forgot about `literal_eval`. I also was thinking about using `json.loads`. Let’s see if the OP can clarify the origin of the string, because that doesn’t look right for any automated output.

Comment: The origin seems to be .pyc files. Might be that the OP used a flawed extraction process which introduced these spaces...